# App freezes after deleting UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

There is a problem when I try to delete **UITableViewCell** in success block of the request.

In my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I am making request with AFNetworking

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
```

After that in success block I am updating UI by dismissing `SVProgressHUD` and deleting cell:

```
NSUserDefaults *usd = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[usd removeObjectForKey:@"payViaCreditCard"];
selectedCardID = nil;

[[CreditCardManager sharedCreditCardManager] removeCreditCard:creditCardToDelete];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

In the end my UI not updating and app freezes, when I relaunch the app the data in NSUserDefaults changed.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but there's no point calling `reloadData` after `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: Remove `reloadData` and you should be good to go.

Comment: My UITableView always has one checkmark, so after reloadData if UITableViewCell with checkmark deleted, by default first cell will has checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good if you do either `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` or `tableView reloadData`.

```
    [[CreditCardManager sharedCreditCardManager] removeCreditCard:creditCardToDelete];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    OR 

    [[CreditCardManager sharedCreditCardManager] removeCreditCard:creditCardToDelete];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Second way did not help me, I tried the first before posting the question, but my UITableView has always one checkmark, so after deleting cell I need to reloadData

Comment: Reload you tableview after some delay, may make trick, I have done, for my case.

Comment: Reloading after delay working, but I can not understand why app freezes when trying to reload immediately.

Comment: At the time when UITableViewRowAnimationFade animation gets animated, same time reloading will make cohesion.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting cell you should use

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
} 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
   {
      NSUserDefaults *usd = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [usd removeObjectForKey:@"payViaCreditCard"];
      selectedCardID = nil;

      [[CreditCardManager sharedCreditCardManager] removeCreditCard:creditCardToDelete];
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      //[self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: My UITableView always has one checkmark, so after reloadData if UITableViewCell with checkmark deleted, by default first cell will has checkmark.

Comment: @Chika i think rather than reloading the whole table, it will be good to reload the row at 0th index (first cell) after any row with checkmark is deleted

Comment: @Chika, what are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried to reload only the first cell, but result the same

Comment: have you updated the modal to add the checkmark just before reloading the first cell?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. I am adding checkmark in **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;**