# UITableView section deletion problems

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `2 sections` and `1` / `59` rows in them. 
I delete row( so in 0 section i got 0 rows), and got this crash (also breakpoint at `-[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` works). Can't get how this 1 deleted) is calculated so.

```
Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted)
```

I get this message, but there is no deletion of sections at all, breakpoint at `-[UITableView deleteSections:withRowAnimation:]` doesn't work.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Show some more code that you have try.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813878/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-rows-in-section

Comment: there is no call of reloadData between beginUpdates/endUpdates

Comment: After deletion are You updating number of sections?

Answer (score -1):

I think what's happening, but I am not sure because I don't see your code.
I'm going to try explain you what is the proccess to follow when you want delete a row or section in your table.

I supose that you have an array with the rows and other array with the sections.

1 - You must delete a row from the array of rows:

```
arrayRows.removeAtIndex(indexRow)
```

2 - You must delete a section (if is necesary) from the array of sections:

```
arraySections.removeAtIntex(indexSection)
```

3 - Now is the moments to remove the row from the table, using next code:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexRow, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
//If you want delete sections, firstly you must delete all rows of this section
tableView.deleteSections(indexSection, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()

//After this, you must reload data of table
tableView.reloadData()
```

PD: Be sure that your methods numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView get the data from the arrays of rows and sections. Like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arraySections.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Return array of rows of section
    return arrayRows.count
}
```

I hope it helps!!

If you want some doubts please tell me and I try to help you in other way.